# Как посчитать количество одинаковых значений вектора идущих в ряд?

Tags: python, pandas, оптимизация, numpy, обработка-данных

Надо средствами numpy/pandas, без циклов. Производительность имеет значение.

```
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Пример решения с циклом:

```
res = np.full_like(a, np.nan)
counter = 1

for i in range(len(a)):
    if i > 0:
        if a[i] == a[i - 1]:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 1

    res[i] = counter

print(res)
```

### Update: замер скорости с timeit

В моем python окружении пример с pandas работает быстрее всего. Медленнее всего пример с numba.

#### Пример с циклом

```py
import numpy as np
import timeit

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
a = np.concatenate([a] * 10 ** 4)


def count_sequential(a):
    res = np.full_like(a, np.nan)
    counter = 1
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if i > 0:
            if a[i] == a[i - 1]:
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 1

        res[i] = counter
    return res


starttime = timeit.default_timer()
count_sequential(a)
print("Execution time:", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)

# Execution time: 0.086103173
```

#### Пример с pandas

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import timeit

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
a = np.concatenate([a] * 10 ** 4)

starttime = timeit.default_timer()
s = pd.Series(a)
res = s.groupby(s.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
res.to_numpy()
print("Execution time:", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)

# Execution time: 0.015625225999999992
```

#### Пример с numba

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import prange, njit, jit
import timeit

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

a = np.concatenate([a] * 10 ** 4)


@njit  # (['int64[:](int64[:])'])
def count_sequential_numba(a):
    res = np.full_like(a, np.nan)
    counter = 1
    for i in prange(len(a)):
        if i > 0:
            if a[i] == a[i - 1]:
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 1
        res[i] = counter
    return res


starttime = timeit.default_timer()
count_sequential_numba(a)
print("Execution time:", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)

# Execution time: 0.23011980099999996
```

#### Пример с groupby

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
import timeit

a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
a = np.concatenate([a] * 10 ** 4)

starttime = timeit.default_timer()
ans = []
for elem, count in groupby(a):
    c, d = elem, sum(1 for i in count)
    ans.extend(list(range(1, d + 1)))
print("Execution time:", timeit.default_timer() - starttime)

# Execution time: 0.05182988100000002
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вариант векторизированного решения с использованием `Pandas`:

```
s = pd.Series(a)
res = s.groupby(s.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
```

результат:

```
In [14]: res.to_numpy()
Out[14]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 5):

Метод, который быстрее чем через `pandas` от [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211923/maxu) в 200~ раз на коротких массивах.

```
%%timeit
s = pd.Series(a)
res = s.groupby(s.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
# 2.25 ms ± 188 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
from itertools import groupby
ans = []
for elem, count in groupby(a):
    c, d = elem, sum(1 for i in count)
    ans.extend(list(range(1, d + 1)))
# 11.4 µs ± 163 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что если бы автору нужно было это решение для 17 элементов массива, то он не стал бы указывать - `производительность имеет значение` ;)

Comment: В реальной жизни мы больше сталкиваемся с большим количеством мелких массивов, чем наоборот. Но я не пытался как то принизить ваши усилия, а просто показал альтернативное решение)

Comment: На счет реальной жизни согласен, но для мелких массивов мы в реальной жизни  не пытаемся улучшить время выполнения от миллисекунд до микросекунд. А если пытаемся, то что-то не так с подходом и надо задуматься о векторизации 

Comment: _Метод, который быстрее чем через pandas от @MaxU_, дайте ссылку на сообщение, а не на профиль, а то не понятно, какой метод вы имеете в виду

Answer (score 4):

Сравнение скорости выполнения решений для массива, состоящего из 17.000 элементов:

```
In [24]: a = np.concatenate([a] * 1000)

In [25]: len(a)
Out[25]: 17000

In [26]: %%timeit
    ...: s = pd.Series(a)
    ...: res = s.groupby(s.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
    ...: 
    ...: 
1.66 ms ± 59.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [27]: %%timeit
    ...: ans = []
    ...: for elem, count in groupby(a):
    ...:     c, d = elem, sum(1 for i in count)
    ...:     ans.extend(list(range(1, d + 1)))
    ...: 
3.92 ms ± 46.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

PS для более честного сравнения я убрал импорт из блока `%%timeit`...

Comment: Наверняка во втором методе можно перейти на numpy arrays и обойтись без extend списка, тогда быстрее будет )

Comment: @CrazyElf, `"Бремя доказательства лежит на утверждающем"` ;)

Comment: Ради интереса переделал всё что можно на `Numpy` - реально всё-равно второй вариант в 2 раза медленнее. Как так ))

Answer (score 4):

Продолжаем оптимизировать... :)

На этот раз воспользуемся [Numba.njit](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html) (`Just In Time compiler`) - он идеально подходит для оптимизации простых циклов:

```
from numba import prange, njit, jit

@njit #(['int64[:](int64[:])'])
def count_sequential_numba(a):
    res = np.full_like(a, np.nan)
    counter = 1
    for i in prange(len(a)):
        if i > 0:
            if a[i] == a[i - 1]:
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 1
        res[i] = counter
    return res
```

Заметьте функция состоит из оригинального кода из вопроса - я добавил только декоратор.

тест:

```
In [39]: a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [40]: count_sequential_numba(a)
Out[40]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

---

Сравнение производительности для массива, состоящего из 170.000 элементов:

```
In [41]: a = np.concatenate([a] * 10**4)

In [42]: a.shape
Out[42]: (170000,)


In [44]: %%timeit
    ...: ans = []
    ...: for elem, count in groupby(a):
    ...:     c, d = elem, sum(1 for i in count)
    ...:     ans.extend(list(range(1, d + 1)))
    ...:
73.9 ms ± 626 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [45]: %%timeit
    ...: s = pd.Series(a)
    ...: res = s.groupby(s.diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
    ...:
23.1 ms ± 1.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [46]: %%timeit
    ...: res = count_sequential_numba(a)
    ...:
207 µs ± 115 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

### Выигрыш - в 357 раз по сравнению с [`itertools.groupby`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199243/211923) и в 112 раз посравнению с [`Pandas`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1198459/211923):

```
In [47]: 73.9 * 1000 / 207
Out[47]: 357.0048309178744

In [48]: 23.1 * 1000 / 207
Out[48]: 111.59420289855072
```

Comment: Ну numba это читерство :)

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, в моей работе главное не участие, а результат ;)

Comment: @MaxU, добавил в описание свои примеры замеров. Решение с pandas работает быстрее всего.

Comment: @nick, советую использовать `%timeit` в ipython/Jupyter для замеров времени, т.к. одного запуска мало, чтобы собрать статистику

Comment: @nick, перепроверил на другом компьютере - решение с Numba все еще на порядки быстрее...

Comment: @MaxU, Numba плохо проверяется через timeit, к сожалению, там кэшируются вызовы, попробуйте через time два раза ячейку прогнать, вы поймете о чем я)

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, насколько я знаю в Numba кэшируются только скомпилированные функции. Если запускать два раза ячейку, то и компилировать мы будем два раза. Не думаю что время компиляции стоит замерять для __каждого__ запуска...

Comment: аа, вот оно что, не знал.

Comment: @MaxU, попробовал Jupyter c %timeit и действительно, numba там быстрее всех.

Comment: Но расчеты я делаю не в Jupyter. А через запуск интрепретатора в терминале. Через терминал намба работает медленнее всех.

Comment: @nick, потому что учитывается время компиляции. Попробуйте замерять время как показано в верхних примерах [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) - из командной строки

Comment: Понял, в зависимости от метода замера получаем разные результаты.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант для обычных массивов и с использованием строк

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

a = str(a)[1:-1]
a = a.replace("-1", "0")
a = a.replace(", ", "")
a = a.replace("10", "1 0").replace("01", "0 1")
n = map(lambda x: list(range(1, len(x) + 2)), a.split())

print(sum(n, start = []))
```